# How to make two sub-sets each with two distinct elements having a list with 4 elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, subset

Consider the following list:

```
list = {{meson1, p1}, {meson2, p2}, {meson3, p3}, {meson4, p4}}
```

I would like to organize it into two sub-sets, each with two elements, with no repetitions. Say,

```
listfinal = {{{{meson1,p1},{meson2,p2}},{{meson3,p3},{meson4,p4}}}, {{{meson1,p1},{meson3,p3}},{{meson2,p2},{meson4,p4}}}, ...}
```

where we have, e.g., the following first pair of 2-subsets:

```
{{{meson1,p1},{meson2,p2}},{{meson3,p3},{meson4,p4}}}
```

The subset `{{meson4,p4},{meson2,p2}}` is a duplicate of `{{meson2,p2},{meson4,p4}}`.

I know that there is a command

```
Subsets[list, {2}]
```

but it does not do exactly what I want: one more action is missing - I need to combine the elements of the 2-subsets such that I will get `listfinal`. Could you please tell me how to obtain `listfinal`?

P.S. In my real example, meson1, meson2, etc (but not p1,...), are strings, and it may be that "meson2" is the same as "meson1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case in question only:

```
({#,Complement[list, #]}&/@Subsets[#, {2},3)&@list


(* {
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson2, p2}}, {{meson3, p3}, {meson4, p4}}}, 
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson3, p3}}, {{meson2, p2}, {meson4, p4}}}, 
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson4, p4}}, {{meson2, p2}, {meson3, p3}}}
   } *)
```

Or

```
({#,Complement[list, #]}&/@Subsets[#, {2},Binomial[Length@#,2]/2])&@list

 (* {
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson2, p2}}, {{meson3, p3}, {meson4, p4}}}, 
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson3, p3}}, {{meson2, p2}, {meson4, p4}}}, 
    {{{meson1, p1}, {meson4, p4}}, {{meson2, p2}, {meson3, p3}}}
   } *)
```

```
({#,Complement[Range[4], #]}&/@Subsets[#,{2},Binomial[Length@#,2]/2])&@Range[4]

(* {
    {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
    {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, 
    {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}
   } *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

list = {{"meson1", p1}, {"meson2", p2}, {"meson3", p3}, {"meson4", 
    p4}};

Cases[KSetPartitions[list, 2], {Repeated[{_, _}, {2}]}]
```

> {{{{"meson1", p1}, {"meson2", p2}}, {{"meson3", p3}, {"meson4",
> p4}}}, {{{"meson1", p1}, {"meson4", p4}}, {{"meson2",
> p2}, {"meson3", p3}}}, {{{"meson1", p1}, {"meson3",
> p3}}, {{"meson2", p2}, {"meson4", p4}}}}